# GeoServer REST API for NetCDF in Python

Tags: python, geoserver, netcdf, rest, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to programmatically edit the dimension variable in GeoServer for  200+ NetCDF's.

This is how I am trying it:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog
cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/", username=conf_dict['GEOSERVER_USER'], password=conf_dict['GEOSERVER_PASS'])
from geoserver.support import DimensionInfo
coverage = cat.get_resource_by_url(conf_dict['GEOSERVER_HOST'] + "/rest/workspaces/daressalaam/coveragestores/201903030300_grid_FloodForecast_V2/coverages/201903030300_grid_FloodForecast_V2.xml")
timeInfo = DimensionInfo("time", "true", "LIST", None, "ISO8601", None)
coverage.metadata = ({'dirName':'201903030300_grid_FloodForecast_V2', 'time': timeInfo})
cat.save(coverage)
```

I've copied the above code from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213681/add-time-dimension-to-vector-layer-in-geoserver-rest) and [here](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/python_gsconfig.html#updating-the-imagemosaic)

yet when I run the code, I get an attribute error message

> AttributeError: 'DimensionInfo' object has no attribute 'unitSymbol'

What am I doing wrong?
How can I programmatically edit the time variable for all my NetCDFs in GeoServer?

Comment: looks like gsconfig is out of date or you are using an old version

Comment: I just checked with pip, I have version: gsconfig-py3==1.0.7. That is the latest version.

Comment: doesn't mean it has kept up with GeoServer

Comment: So what are you saying, that gsconfig and geoserver are out of sync?

Comment: seems like it - you need to look at the XML being sent and what GeoServer expects (unitSymbol)

Comment: where can i find what Geoserver expects?

Comment: see the accepted answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213681/add-time-dimension-to-vector-layer-in-geoserver-rest

Comment: thanks for sending the continued help! 
The link you send was the link i mentioned in my question. I use the exact same syntax as is shown in the link you send. and it still breaks with same error message

Comment: if you read the **accepted** answer you will see how to find out what GeoServer is expecting - basically make the change in the GUI and then make a GET request to see the required format

Comment: i eventually did it using REST api directly, instead of wrapper of gsconifg. I wouldn't know which GET request I needed to do. after some trial and error, the XML-model i show in the answer below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so eventually, I skipped using the python package gsconfig, and applied the an xml model as is shown in this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213681/add-time-dimension-to-vector-layer-in-geoserver-rest).

However, I made some alterations:

- I used it for a NetCDF, not a shapefile.
- PUT request instead of POST.
- presentation value LIST instead of CONTINUOUS_INTERVAL, and
- Default value of NONE instead of MAXIMUM

.

```
   url = """<coverage>
                <title>{new_title_layer}</title>
                <metadata>
                    <entry key="time">
                    <dimensionInfo>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <attribute>time_attribute</attribute>
                    <presentation>LIST</presentation>
                    <units>ISO8601</units>
                    <defaultValue>NONE</defaultValue>
                    </dimensionInfo>
                    </entry>
                </metadata>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </coverage>""".format(new_title_layer=new_title_layer)

    r_change_name = requests.put("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/"+ workspace  + "/coveragestores/" + coveragestore +  "/coverages/" + coveragestore,
                                 auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin","geoserver",
                                 data=url,
                                 headers={'content-type': 'text/xml'})
```